# Get data from textarea in HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I am trying to print out to Python what the user types inside the `textarea` element in the HTML page.

[image: example]

If I type "hello world" into the textarea field and click the button 'Add comment', I would like to see it print out to the Python console. Can anyone help me with this?

```
a = ""

a += '<html> \r\n'
a += '<head> \r\n'
a += '</head> \r\n'
a += '<body> \r\n'
a += '<form method="post"> \r\n'
a +=  '<textarea name="comment101" style="width:300px; height: 70px; maxlength="300"; display:none;"> \r\n'
a +=  '</textarea></br> \r\n'
a +=  '<input type="submit" name="comment101" value="Add comment" /> \r\n'
a +=  '</form> \r\n'
a += '</body> \r\n'
a += '</html> \r\n'

b = open("test.html", "wb")
b.write(a)
b.close()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how you are serving this to a browser? and accepting a response from the form? django? flask? You seem to be saving html to a file and that is all

Comment: I created a html page e.g. test.html using python. In the test.html, there are textarea field and a button like the picture above. When I type "hello world" in the textarea field at test.html, and click the 'Add Comment' button, I want it to print out at Python. I'm not sure how to do that, so at the moment my code is saving test.html only.

Answer (score 0):

So looking from your conversion in the comments you seem to be a bit confused as how this works. You cannot use python natively  to listen to a button click of an html file and then retrieve this information. Your going to need a framework in between to help you do this. I have listed some of the following below.

[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) - This is my personal favorite, its light weight and easy to understand. As it says on their website this is not a full blown framework its a microframework. Easy to use and understand, a great place to start learning about frameworks.

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) - Much more advanced a quite a bit more complicated to start learning. This framework has tons of features and its great in many cases. Its going to be a bit harder for someone new to frameworks to understand Django.

Both of these are going to require quite a bit of reading but are well worth it and will be a great way to advance your programming skills.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CherryPy, which is a minimalist python framework which can help you achieve connecting your html code with native python code. [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/)
You can go through the documentation to easily achieve what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) to be honest. They have an excellent [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/) to get you up and running. It is also feature complete as a framework. When you get more comfortable with Python and Django, I would move to frameworks like Flask that are excellent but require you to assemble the pieces.

But you will likely need to learn more about [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), which is made easier with the [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), and [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) before you get started on that adventure

I would be happy to answer any additional questions you may have... Python and it's associated frameworks and tools are such a joy to work with.

[Codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) has some good and free tutorials btw